# How to add information to MySQL database using java code

Tags: java, mysql

Below, there's code that should insert information to the MySQL database. It works without exceptions, but does not insert information to the database.

```
    try {
        Class.forName("Com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection connection= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql:///mymail","root","toor");
        out.print("Connected");
        PreparedStatement ps= connection.prepareStatement("insert into mytable(fname,lname,uname,pass,cpass,month,day,year,Gender,mobile,email,country) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
    ps.setString(1, fname);
    ps.setString(2, lname);
    ps.setString(3, uname);
    ps.setString(4, pass);
    ps.setString(5, cpass);
    ps.setString(6, month);
    ps.setString(7, day);
    ps.setString(8, year);
    ps.setString(9, Gender);
    ps.setString(10, mobile);
    ps.setString(11,email);
    ps.setString(12, country);
    ps.executeUpdate();

    } catch (Exception e) 
                        {}
```

Comment: You don't display your whole code, but I suspect that getting no error is the result of silently swallowing it in that catch statement.

Comment: Can we see code handling Exception?

Comment: if you are not viewing any exception.. add this in your catch block `e.printStackTrace();`for viewing full trace or `System.out.println(e);` for viewing the exception alone.. 


P.S: Always remember to post your exceptions or errors when you ask a question. That will help us in answering your question better. We cant assume all possible errors.. So, to get the right answer post your errors/exception

Comment: There was neither any error nor any exception.it compiles succesfully but then also there is not any insertion in database. and i have already added e.printStackTrace(); but result is same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well without the complete code and table structure it's hard to tell what is causing the problem. Though I would suggest you check the type of your columns with the values you are inserting. That's potentially could be causing the problem.

Secondly the url you are specifying for database looks suspicious.

And lastly make sure you have a mysql connector in your classpath.

If you've checked the above points, I think you should be good.

Comment: Ohh thanks, actually i didn't had used mysql connector. Now i got it.

Answer (score 1):

It might be that your connection is not in autocommit mode, so you have to call a `connection.commit()`.

And you must call `connection.close()` (in a finally block) before you leave that method, otherwise you will leak open connections

I would suggest you try a framework that saves you a lot of those troubles like spring with [JdbcTemplates](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html#jdbc-JdbcTemplate-examples).

Comment: In java 7, is it necessary to close jdbc connection ? I think not.

Comment: But then you would have to use a try block with [try-with-ressource](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)